# mvc3 on iis6 , only home page works , routes gives 404

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-3

I've deployed a MVC3 application to a win2003 server with .Net4.0 installed . I've configured wildcard mapping for application as described [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) . Also i did it before for other mvc3 applications on the same server before . I'm sure that the IIS configurations of both mvc3 applications are same.

When i hit the default home page of the default route, it works, but other controllers and actions gives 404. I can't figure out a way for 2 days . Any help will be great.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters 
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults );
```

Comment: Could you please show the routing in global.asax.cs

Comment: `code`routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                  "Default", // Route name
                  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: You might have to declare more routes, specially if you have more than one parameter.

Comment: All routes have the same expressions . I dont think i have to declare more routes .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that ASP.NET 4.0 is properly registered with IIS 6.0

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

and that it is enabled:

[image]

Comment: yes , its already registered . And there are also other mvc3 applications on the same server running properly.

Comment: I have this problem to, do you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Verify below items in IIS
Home Directory tab -> Configuration. Under Wildcard application maps,
1.the entry aspnet_isapi.dll has been added 
2."verify file exists" checkbox should be in **unchecked** state